# Animate two humanoids in one animation

Tags: unity-game-engine

I’ve been going through the animation videos on [learn.unity.com](https://learn.unity.com). There, it demonstrates how to animate a *single* humanoid, but how would I go about creating an animation that involves more than one humanoid?

My interest case is a pro wrestling game, where one wrestler would execute a manoeuvre on another wrestler. My instinct is that the manoeuvre would be a single animation, rather than one model having an “attack” animation and another model having a “receive” animation? That feels like it would be a pain to coordinate and keep synchronised.

Comment: Checkout the [Timeline](https://unity3d.com/de/unity/features/editor/art-and-design/timeline) I think it solves exactly what you are looking for. It is basically a better form of `Animator` but can use Scene references and keep track of multiple different objects. It is still up to you ofcourse whether to have to separate animations or one including both objects ..

Answer (score 0):

Well. you could use a transform and attach the affected humanoid to it. This way you could use the animation of the first humanoid to manipulate this transform and indirectly the 2nd one.
Additionally you will probably need animations on the 2nd humanoid as well. They would be triggered by the first agent?

Not sure if that is the correct way. But browsing the animations i own, i notice there are always single animations per humanoid, even if the humanoid would interact with the second one. In short: single animations per humanoid. (e.g. handshakes or dance animations :) )

also i found this: [How do i make a two-character (interacting) animation?](https://answers.unity.com/questions/686900/how-do-i-make-a-two-character-interacting-animatio.html)